# Create a column in dataframe having a String(SELECT statement)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe has `table_name` and `column_name` as its column.
I want to create a column in dataframe with the string format as below:

```
"SELECT {} from databasename.{}".format(df['Column_Name'],df['Table_name'])
```

How can I apply it for all the rows?

Comment: Can u include some sample input.

Comment: please add some examples of what you want.

Comment: `"SELECT " + df['column name'] + " FROM " + df['table_name']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# this is my dummy dataframe. 
df = pd.DataFrame({"Table_name": ["users", "product"], "Column_Name": ["first_name", "prod_id"]})

df.apply(lambda x: "SELECT {} from databasename.{}".format(x['Column_Name'],x['Table_name']),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    SELECT first_name from databasename.users
1     SELECT prod_id from databasename.product
```